# Read charts from .xlsx file in Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library to read [`.xlsx`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) files in Python. I need to read some information (title, series names etc) about charts embedded in worksheets. Documentation mentions only [creating new charts](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/introduction.html), and reading existing charts is nowhere mentioned.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("charts.xlsx")
for sheet in wb:
    # wb.???
```

Comment: Can you share your xlsx sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the current version of OpenPyXL does not allow to load charts from Excel files. If you load a Workbook and immediately save it to the same filename you will effectively remove the charts from it.

Comment: As I noticed (Python 3.8.5), already created charts are not being removed when I save the file. But I can't access an already created chart object from Python (still looking for a way).

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing with the same issue and my ownly workaround is using pywin32 library (which doesn't work for linux obviously) provided here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68173137/8139118