# Get Excel chart details to Python

Tags: python, excel, linux, openpyxl

I have an excel file which has the charts on a separate sheets and they have multiple series plotted on them. What I need to do is to plot exactly the same ranges using python. By the range I mean the following:

[image]

Is there a way to access this information via python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

**Option 1** for all sheets

```
import win32com.client as client


def series_output(chart):
    print(f'\tChart name is {chart.Name}')
    for sc in chart.SeriesCollection():
        print(f'\t\t{sc.Name}: {sc.Formula}')


xl = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'c:\test\Charts.xlsm')
for sh in wb.Sheets:
    print(f'Processed sheet {sh.Name}')
    if sh.Type == -4100:  # it's chart sheet
        series_output(sh)
    elif sh.Type == -4167:  # it's worksheet with (possible) charts
        for ch in sh.ChartObjects():
            series_output(ch.Chart)
wb.Close(False)  # don't save & close workbook
xl.Quit()
```

**Option 2** for a specific sheet

```
import win32com.client as client


def series_output(chart):
    print(f'\tChart name is {chart.Name}')
    for sc in chart.SeriesCollection():
        print(f'\t\t{sc.Name}: {sc.Formula}')


xl = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'c:\test\Charts.xlsm')  # your own path\name
sh = wb.Sheets('Sheet1')  # your own worksheet name
print(f'Processed sheet {sh.Name}')
for ch in sh.ChartObjects():
    series_output(ch.Chart)
wb.Close(False)  # don't save & close workbook
xl.Quit()
```

Comment: getting this error:                                                                                                     `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)`

Comment: replace `c:\test\Charts.xlsm` with your own workbook path\name in `wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'c:\test\Charts.xlsm')`

Comment: Yep, I changed it initially. Now, changed the name of the file to something simpler (like "file.xslx") and it just gives me just `Exception occurred`.

Comment: I didn't mention that in the question, but I would like to access specific sheet in excel.

Comment: First, make sure that the file you specified really exists in the path you specified. Regarding the processing of charts on a particular sheet, see Option 2 code

Comment: I was able to reproduce the above error by specifying the name of a workbook that does not exist

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code snippets above, one more question...is there a way to replicate the same algorithm but using openpyxl lib?